# How can I replicate a query to pull data side by side?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query, and what I am trying to do is take the query data, replicate it but change the names on the column headers from FY14 Q1 to FY14 Q2 and change the filters in the query.

Is there a way I can have this data shown all in one big table by combining the different queries??? Please help.

```
Select H.OpportunityID, H.CREATEDDATE, H.STAGENAME as 'Q1-14 Stage', H.CLOSEDATE as 'Q1-14 Close Date'
From 
(SELECT
    OpportunityID, Max(CREATEDDATE) as MaxDate          
FROM [BVSFWarehouse].[dbo].[sf_OPPORTUNITYHISTORY]
WHERE
    CREATEDDATE  <= '2013-05-01'  
GROUP BY
     OpportunityID) X 
Join [BVSFWarehouse].[dbo].[sf_OPPORTUNITYHISTORY] H ON H.OpportunityID = X.OpportunityID
     And X.MaxDate = H.CREATEDDATE
```

Comment: What you want is possible, if a bit complicated.  It may be easier to use a pivot to get what you want.  What does your data look like and what are your desired results?

Comment: For the SQL table I need 2 columns for each quarter starting at Q1-14 through Q1-16. Each quarter should have one  column showing the stage and one showing the close date that deals had on the first day of that quarter.  So a column for the stage name, opportunity ID, last modified date,  and close date.  That would be one query.  The next query would be the same thing with the next quarter.  I want this all on one table.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So 2014-01-01 is the first day of quarter 1/2014. In case there is data on that day for an OpportunityID, show this. Otherwise look backwards until there is a day with data for the OpportunityID. Yes? So 2013-12-20 could be the "first day" for quarter 1/2014? And if there has not been any data for the OpportunityID for several months, the "first day" for quarter 1/2014 could even be 2013-04-04 for instance?